# ¿por qué mi ruta post no funciona?

Tags: nodejs, express

Tengo este error en mi movies router creo que se debe a una mala implementación de `post` y no se a que se debe.

> error: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'path' of undefined
>       at router.post (C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\FullStack\vidly\vidly-backend\routes\movies.js:57:24)

```js
const { Movie, validate } = require("../models/movie");
const { Genre } = require("../models/genre");
const auth = require("../middleware/auth");
const admin = require("../middleware/admin");
const validateObjectId = require("../middleware/validateObjectId");
const moment = require("moment");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const multer = require ("multer");
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'public/img/');
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname);
  }
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if(file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
}

const upload = multer({ 
    storage: storage, 
    limits: { fileSize: 1024*1024*5 },
    fileFilter: fileFilter 
});

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const movies = await Movie.find()
    .select("-__v")
    .sort("name");
  res.send(movies);
});

router.post("/", upload.single('movieImg'), [auth], async (req, res) => {
  const { error } = validate(req.body);
  if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

  const genre = await Genre.findById(req.body.genreId);
  if (!genre) return res.status(400).send("Invalid genre.");

  const movie = new Movie({
    title: req.body.title,
    genre: {
      _id: genre._id,
      name: genre.name
    },
    numberInStock: req.body.numberInStock,
    dailyRentalRate: req.body.dailyRentalRate,
    movieImg: req.file.path,
    publishDate: moment().toJSON()
  });
  await movie.save();

  res.send(movie);
});

router.put("/:id", upload.single('movieImg'), [auth], async (req, res) => {
  const { error } = validate(req.body);
  if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

  const genre = await Genre.findById(req.body.genreId);
  if (!genre) return res.status(400).send("Invalid genre.");

  const movie = await Movie.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.id,
    {
      title: req.body.title,
      genre: {
        _id: genre._id,
        name: genre.name
      },
      numberInStock: req.body.numberInStock,
      dailyRentalRate: req.body.dailyRentalRate,
      movieImg: req.file.path
    },
    { new: true }
  );

  if (!movie)
    return res.status(404).send("The movie with the given ID was not found.");

  res.send(movie);
});

router.delete("/:id", [auth, admin], async (req, res) => {
  const movie = await Movie.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id);

  if (!movie)
    return res.status(404).send("The movie with the given ID was not found.");

  res.send(movie);
});

router.get("/:id", validateObjectId, async (req, res) => {
  const movie = await Movie.findById(req.params.id).select("-__v");

  if (!movie)
    return res.status(404).send("The movie with the given ID was not found.");

  res.send(movie);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: esta parte `publishDate: moment().toJSON()` no necesita de una fecha para que moment la use??? un `new Date()` por ejemplo

Comment: la parte que tiene el error es la parte de la imagen `movieImg: req.file.path` pero no se porque, lo demas esta bien.

Comment: ya intentaste esto?: `movieImg: req.files.NOMBRE_EN_FORMULARIO.path`

Comment: la verdad estoy teniendo problemas en todas mis rutas desde que agregue la funcionalidad para subir imagenes hasta tengo un ** Cannot GET / **  error en localhost:3900 y mis post y put tampoco funcionan.